# What's the difference between <?> and <? extends Object> in Java Generics?

Tags: java, syntax, generics

I've seen the wildcard  used before to mean any object - but recently saw a use of:

```
<? extends Object>
```

Since all objects extend Object, are these two usages synonymous?

Comment: It's the same thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274720/java-extends-object-question

Comment: @Dan If you search "? extends Object" in that question you don't find anything.  I'm reading through the answers to see if I can infer anything but I don't think this is it.  Specifically, it's not talking about generics.

Comment: @Dan - That's a different question. I have seen this question before and I remember at least a mention of a subtle difference. Let me see if I can find it..

Comment: It's also not this one if you find it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678822/what-is-the-difference-between-and-object-in-java-generics

Comment: Here we go: possible duplicate of [Unbounded wildcards in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016017/unbounded-wildcards-in-java) (Featuring an incorrect answer by Kevin Bourrillion no less.)

Comment: @KublaiKhan hmm the accepted answer talks about how this should not be used, rather than why you would use the syntax, so I didn't find it satisfying.  The notnoop answer has good information, but I'm curious how reifiability would affect the usage in this case.  Someone pins that down they get my point and will make this a unique question ;)

Comment: I'm open to changing the green checkbox if someone comes up with the actual answer.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`<?>` and `<? extends Object>` are synonymous, as you'd expect.

There are a few cases with generics where `extends Object` is not actually redundant. For example, `<T extends Object & Foo>` will cause `T` to become `Object` under erasure, whereas with `<T extends Foo>` it will become `Foo` under erasure. (This can matter if you're trying to retain compatibility with a pre-generics API that used `Object`.)

Source: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html; it explains why the JDK's `java.util.Collections` class has a method with this signature:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(
    Collection<? extends T> coll
)
```

Comment: I'm unclear how the example relates?  (as it uses neither <?> nor <? extends Object>)

Comment: @orbfish: It relates only in that I thought you would find it interesting, as it's an example where `extends Object` actually *is* meaningful. If I was mistaken, then I apologize. Hopefully it will be of interest to other people coming across your question, at least.

Comment: @ruakh - Was interested in bounded wildcards rather than type parameters, but, at least, you answered.

Comment: You should have stated that in your original post then.  That way, his answer could have been more relevant to you.

Answer (score 21):

Although `<?>` is supposed to be a shortcut for `<? extend object>`, there is a tiny difference between the two.
`<?>` is reifiable while `<? extend object>` is not. The reason they did this is to make it easier to distinguish reifiable type. Anything that looks like `<? extends something>`,`<T>`,`<Integer>` are nonreifiable.

For example, this code would work

```
List aList = new ArrayList<>();
boolean instanceTest = aList instanceof List<?>;
```

but this gives an error

```
List aList = new ArrayList<>();
boolean instancetest = aList instanceof List<? extends Object>;
```

for more info read Java generics and collections by Maurice Naftalin

Comment: How can List<?> be reifiable if compiler will translate it to List<Object> so information about what is the type of ? is lost?

Comment: What I believe <?> is more designed for backward compatible with legacy APIs.
to distinguish with <Object> and <? extends Object> which are post Java 5 code.

Answer (score 15):

`<?>` is a shorthand for `<? extends Object>`. 
You may read below shared link for more details.

---

```
<?>
```

`"?"` denotes any unknown type, It can represent any Type at in code for. Use this wildcard if you are not sure about Type.

```
ArrayList<?> unknownList = new ArrayList<Number>(); //can accept of type Number
unknownList = new ArrayList<Float>(); //Float is of type Number
```

**Note:** `<?>` means anythings. So It can accept of Type which are not inherited from `Object` class.

```
<? extends Object>
```

`<? extends Object>` means you can pass an Object or a sub-class that extends `Object` class.

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Number>(); //Number of subclass
numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Integer extends Number
numberList = new ArrayList<Float>(); // Float extends Number
```

---

[image]

T – used to denote type
E – used to denote element
K – keys
V - values
N – for numbers
[Ref:](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html)

[image]

Comment: "So It can accept of Type which are not inherited from Object class", but all Java classes are inherited or implicitly inherited from the `Object` class.