# Java Generics restrict to interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but what I want to accomplish is this:

```
public static <A,B extends SomeClass & A> B makeB(A thing) {...}
```

Essentially, using a reflection/generation driven process, I want to provide a thing of type B, where B is of class `SomeClass` and implements interface A, and A is user-supplied through Generics.

I am not asking about the mechanics of generating B - I have that under control.  What I'm looking for is a way to restrict generic type argument `<A>` to interfaces, not classes, so that I can use the syntax `B extends SomeClass & A` for clean type safety.

Is this possible?  Is anyone aware of an alternative approach to this problem?

---

Edit:  I guess I didn't express myself very clearly, as it seems to be causing confusion in the comments:

`B` is intended to be a placeholder for a wildcard, so that the client can get a single object that is both a `SomeClass` and an `A` without having to do casting based on trust.  The client will not have access to the name of the actual class that implements `SomeClass` and `A`, because it's being generated at compile time, hence this issue regarding type safety.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: This gives me a sad face :(

Comment: On the other hand, if you want a reflection-driven thing, you could just pass a `Class<A>` and explicitly call `Class.isInterface()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman He already has an instance of A as a parameter. He can get Class<A> from that. He doesn't need another parameter.

Comment: Does `SomeClass` have anything to do with the detail of creating `B`? If yes, you should correlate `SomeClass` to either `A` or `B` and refactor to a cleaner signature. If no, you can simply use `public static <A,B extends A> B makeB(A thing) {...}`.

Comment: There's actually multiple `SomeClass`'s, so to speak.  I need to generate four or five different classes that all implement `A` but have different base interfaces - they all do fundamentally different things.

Comment: I think the problem here is returning a `B` from this method.  You pass `B` as a type parameter, but it never appears anywhere else in the method signature.  How is the compiler supposed to infer the return type from the arguments????  Seems like you should return either a `SomeClass` or an `A`.  Either one can be a `B` under the hood, but should appear as a `SomeClass` or an `A` to the client code.

Comment: @jahroy Sorry, I didn't get a chance to see your comment to me until after you deleted your answer. Your point about inferring `B` is absolutely right - I actually mentioned a similar concern in the edit to my answer. You should definitely undelete your answer because it's helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to impose such a compile-time restriction. Generic type parameters are stand-ins for reference types; they make no distinction between class types and interface types. The fact that additional bounds in a type parameter's declaration must be interface types is merely incidental - your strategy to leverage this as a means to impute a type as an interface was clever, but it's defeated by the limitation that type parameters [can't be used in multiple bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds).

Your only options are to settle for a runtime check using [`Class.isInterface()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29) like Louis Wasserman [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622820/java-generics-restrict-to-interface/17689599#comment25655203_17622820), or to leave it up to the caller to be responsible with what it passes in. Either way, make sure to clearly document the method's expectations and behavior.

---

> `B` is intended to be a placeholder for a wildcard, so that the client can get a single object that is both a `SomeClass` and an `A` without having to do casting based on trust. The client will not have access to the name of the actual class that implements `SomeClass` and `A`

This seems like a contradiction to me. There's no point to declaring `B` if the caller can't possibly know what it evaluates to. Remember: the caller of a generic method provides its type arguments. So a caller deciding `B` without anything to base it on can only be guessing - and that can never be type-safe.

It seems like what you really want your method to return is some type that is both a `SomeClass` and an `A`, but this is tricky because they don't share a common supertype:

```
public static <A> SomeClass&A makeSomeClass(A thing) {...}
```

(this is [nonsensical syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464226/how-to-reference-a-generic-return-type-with-multiple-bounds) for demonstration purposes only)

As a workaround, consider alternative ways to represent both a `SomeClass` and some interface type. For example the candidate interfaces could have a common method for returning a `SomeClass`:

```
public interface IsSomeClass {
    SomeClass asSomeClass();
}

public interface Foo extends IsSomeClass { }
```

The implementation of `asSomeClass` would in fact just return `this`. Then you could do:

```
public static <A extends IsSomeClass> A makeSomeClass(Class<A> type) {...}
```

And the caller of that method would be able to use the returned object as either type:

```
final Foo foo = makeSomeClass(Foo.class);
final SomeClass someClass = foo.asSomeClass();
```

If the interfaces themselves can't be modified, then another option is to use a wrapper class and composition instead:

```
final class SomeClassWrapper<A> {

    private final SomeClass someClass;
    private final A a;

    //constructor and getters, etc.
}
```

And your method would return a wrapper instance instead, assigning the implementation instance to *both* `someClass` and `a`:

```
public static <A> SomeClassWrapper<A> makeSomeClass(Class<A> type) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `SomeClass` is always a class, the `A` in `<B extends SomeClass & A>` *can only be* an interface, because there is no multiple inheritance in Java. The only way `& A` can be satisfied is if `A` is an interface.

Comment: you might be overlooked, but the compiler complains: The type A is not an interface; it cannot be specified as a bounded parameter

Comment: @jahroy and @EJP you seem to be overlooking that `A` is a type parameter in `<A,B extends SomeClass & A>`, which is why that doesn't compile.

Comment: yeah...you are right...but there is no way to tell the compiler that the generic argument will be an interface?

Comment: @ZoltánNagy That's the *point.* If the actual type argument supplied as `A` isn't an interface the compiler complains.

Comment: @ZoltánNagy - The point of generics is to get the compiler to help you enforce type safety.  If you want `A` to be an interface and the compiler complains when it is not, then generics are doing their job.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you want to return a `B` from this method.

You specify `B` as a type parameter, but it never appears anywhere else in the method signature.

How is the compiler supposed to infer the return type from the arguments????

There is no opportunity for the client code to specify what `B` is.

It seems like you should return either a `SomeClass` or an `A`.

Either one can be a `B` under the hood, but should appear as a `SomeClass` or an `A` to the client code.