# Array of Generics Can not Cast to Object to Comparable Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I want to create a class which accepts generics in Java, but I want to also enforce the Generic to implement the `Comparable` interface. This is the code

```
public class MyClass<Item extends Comparable> {

private Item[] items;
private Item[] copies;

public MyClass(Item[] items) {
    this.items = items;
    copies=  (Item[])new Object[items.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        copies[i] = items[i];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] items = {23, 36, 45, 66, 25, 38, 47};

    MyClass<Integer> myClass= new MyClass<Integer>(items);
   
   }
}
```

As I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to 
class [Ljava.lang.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

How should I refactor this code to get it working but also
enforce it to accept only Comparable Generics and also leave the instantiating of the `copies` inside the constructor of the `MyClass`?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622820/java-generics-restrict-to-interface

Comment: Arrays and generics don’t play nice: better to use collections. Also, you’re going to want to code `Item extends Comparable<Item>`. Actually, `T extends Comparable<T>` is preferred, because `Item` looks like a class name, which is confusing: The java standard is the generic params are 1 letter.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Comparable` array instead of an `Object` array.

```
this.copies = (Item[]) new Comparable[items.length];
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/bHv4wg)</kbd>