# How to pass multiple generic parameters when extending a generic class

Tags: java, generics

The following will not compile but I wish to create something of similar functionality which will compile:

```
public class FreezerTest
{
interface Edible{}
interface SmallerThanABeachball{}
interface Freezeable{}
abstract class BoxedItem
    {}
class Marbles extends BoxedItem
    {}
class IceCream extends BoxedItem implements Freezeable, SmallerThanABeachball, Edible
    {}
class MyBrother
    {}
class Banana implements Edible, SmallerThanABeachball
    {}
class Cat implements SmallerThanABeachball
    {}

abstract class StorageChest<T>{
    public void add(T toStore){}
    }

class MiniFoodFreezer extends StoreageChest<Freezeable & Edible & SmallerThanABeachball>{
    }

public FreezerTest(){
    MiniFoodFreezer freezer = new MiniFoodFreezer();
    freezer.add(new Cat());//DESIRE COMPILE ERROR
    freezer.add(new IceCream());//DESIRE OK
    freezer.add(new MyBrother());///DESIRE COMPILE ERROR
    freezer.add(new Banana());//DESIRE COMPILER ERROR
    freezer.add(new Marbles());//DESIRE COMPILER ERROR
    }
}//end
```

One thought was to create an all-encompassing interface and then pass that:

```
interface WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer extends Edible, SmallerThanABeachball, Freezeable{}
class MiniFoodFreezer extends StorageChest<WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer>{
}
```

...however what if Edible, SmallerThanABeachball, and Freezeable are all from a 3rd party library and other third-party libraries refer to these types, some of which have the interface implementations necessary meet the criteria for WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer but do not explicitly implement WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to make it a runtime check, or to create an adapter class that wraps IceCream and implements WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `Freezeable & Edible & SmallerThanABeachball` is not itself a type - the ampersand  (`&`) can only be used to define multiple upper bounds when declaring a type parameter, for example `<T extends Freezeable & Edible & SmallerThanABeachball>`. This language limitation is further discussed here: [How to reference a generic return type with multiple bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464226/how-to-reference-a-generic-return-type-with-multiple-bounds)

One workaround is to use a combination of composition and a generic `add` method:

```
class Freezer extends StoreageChest<Freezeable> { }

class MiniFoodFreezer {

    private final Freezer freezer = new Freezer();

    public <T extends Freezeable & Edible & SmallerThanABeachball> void add(
            final T toStore
    ) {
        freezer.add(toStore);
    }
}
```

The downside being that `MiniFoodFreezer` no longer *is-a* `StoreageChest` of anything, so you lose any direct benefits of inheritance. However, you can expose differently typed views of the same objects as needed. For example, assume `StoreageChest<T>` implements `Iterable<T>`:

```
class MiniFoodFreezer {

    private final Freezer freezer = new Freezer();

    public <T extends Freezeable & Edible & SmallerThanABeachball> void add(
            final T toStore
    ) {
        freezer.add(toStore);
    }

    public Iterable<Freezeable> asFreezables() {
        return freezer;
    }

    public Iterable<Edible> asEdibles() {
        // this is okay because add must take an Edible and Iterable is read-only
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Iterable<Edible> edibles = (Iterable<Edible>)(Iterable<?>)freezer;
        return edibles;
    }

    public Iterable<SmallerThanABeachball> asSmallerThanBeachballs() {
        // same reasoning as above
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Iterable<SmallerThanABeachball> smallerThanBeachballs =
                (Iterable<SmallerThanABeachball>)(Iterable<?>)freezer;
        return smallerThanBeachballs;
    }
}
```

Then we can do:

```
final MiniFoodFreezer miniFoodFreezer = new MiniFoodFreezer();
miniFoodFreezer.add(new IceCream());
miniFoodFreezer.add(new SnoCone());
miniFoodFreezer.add(new Slushy());

for (final Freezeable freezable : miniFoodFreezer.asFreezables()) {
    // do freezable stuff
}

for (final Edible edible : miniFoodFreezer.asEdibles()) {
    // do edible stuff
}

for (
        final SmallerThanABeachball smallerThanABeachBall :
        miniFoodFreezer.asSmallerThanBeachballs()
) {
    // do smaller-than-a-beach-ball stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as  JB Nizet say

> I'm afraid you'll have to make it a run-time check, or to create an
>   adapter class that wraps IceCream and implements
>   WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer.

this will solve your problem until java solve its generic nonsense

you suppose the following are in some third party library

```
    interface Edible {
    }

    interface SmallerThanABeachball {
    }

    interface Freezeable {
    }

    abstract class BoxedItem {
    }

    class Marbles extends BoxedItem {
    }

    class IceCream extends BoxedItem implements Freezeable, SmallerThanABeachball, Edible {
    }

    class MyBrother {
    }

    class Banana implements Edible, SmallerThanABeachball {
    }

    class Cat implements SmallerThanABeachball {
    }

    abstract class StorageChest<T> {

        public void add(T toStore) {
        }

    }
    //third party class that has function require type implementing the three interfaces
    class SomeClass{

    <T extends Edible & SmallerThanABeachball & Freezeable> void doSomething(T someThing){
        System.out.println(someThing);
    }

}
```

you want to make your own storage that accept types implementing the three interfaces Edible, SmallerThanABeachball, Freezeable

OK not beautiful one but a simple work around

create interface that implement this interfaces

and create a class that do nothing but extending the target class and implementing the new combining interface

```
    interface WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer extends Edible, SmallerThanABeachball, Freezeable {
    }

    class MiniFoodFreezer extends StorageChest<WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer> {
    }
    //create your one version of iceCream implement the combining interface

    class MyIceCream extends IceCream implements WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer {
    }
    //you can make new types implementing WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer

    class Potato implements WillFitInMiniFoodFreezer {
    }

    class FreezerTest {

        public FreezerTest() {
            MiniFoodFreezer freezer = new MiniFoodFreezer();
            //what you have wished
            freezer.add(new Cat());//DESIRE COMPILE ERROR
            freezer.add(new MyIceCream());//DESIRE OK
            freezer.add(new Potato());//DESIRE OK
            freezer.add(new MyBrother());///DESIRE COMPILE ERROR
            freezer.add(new Banana());//DESIRE COMPILER ERROR
            freezer.add(new Marbles());//DESIRE COMPILER ERROR
    //third party function parametrized with the three interfaces
    SomeClass thirdPartyClass = new SomeClass();
        thirdPartyClass.doSomething(new MyIceCream()); // ^_^ ok
        thirdPartyClass.doSomething(new Potato()); // ^_^ ok
        thirdPartyClass.doSomething(new Cat());//:( not ok
        }

    }//end
```