# How do you enforce that a method parameter type extends a specific class and implements a specific interface?

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters, interface

How do you enforce that a method parameter type both extends a specific class and implements a specific interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple generic parameters when extending a generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716651/how-to-pass-multiple-generic-parameters-when-extending-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 7):

Use `&` to create a union:

```
<T extends Foo & Bar>
```

Everything after the first type must be an interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* 
        A method that will only accept a parameter that :  
        extends SomeClass , AND implements SomeInterface . 
    */
    private < T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface > void someMethod ( T parameter ) 
    {
        // do something ... 
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest giving the answer in the first paragraph and then extend with the explanation. Also the use of identifiers like `CLASS` and `INTERFACE` is going to probably be frowned upon. I would prefer the use of metasyntactic variables like `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` or simply `A`, `B`, `C`, or something less contrived. But other than that +1

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct, but it's hard to find which bit is the actual answer.  It's a one-liner, buried right at the end of the code - and the rest is kind of fluff.  Some explanation would be good too.  Glad the identifier names have been fixed up though.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {}
interface MyInterface {}

public <T extends MyClass & MyInterface> void myMethod(T param) {}
```