# Implementing multiple generic-types in different classes in java

Tags: java, class, generics

How do I most cleverly implement multiple generic parameters that I need in multiple classes (and packages)? Assuming I have the following code to use:

```
public class NewClass<A, B, C, D, E> {...}
```

How do I implement A,B,C,D,E most efficiently if I need these own types in other classes and packages?

Because if I create my own class for the data type (for example the class named "A"), the parametric type A and the created class A will not get along with each other.

Best regards and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716651/how-to-pass-multiple-generic-parameters-when-extending-a-generic-class

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not answer my question. Isn't there a way to replace the generic type with your custom class?