# Why can't generics bounding be overloaded?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around the idea of "fresh-type" variables not allowing for compiling in generics, particularly in the aspect of overloading a method with an already bounded variable:

```
public class Schema {

    private interface Stringable {
        public String s();
    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & Stringable> String getName(T inst) {
        return Schema.getName(inst.getClass()); // error
    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & Stringable> String getName(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.getName().toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

Complilation error:

```
Schema.java:[46,21] error: no suitable method found for getName(Class<CAP#1>)
```

My main question is, why can't things that are suitably bounded for each other be applied under the same generic bounding a second time?

Comment: Can you show the invocation at line 46?

Comment: java doesn't support (real) generics. You're looking for C# ;)

Comment: @yshavit Line 46 is denoted via `//error` in the code above.

Answer (score 4):

When I copy/pasted your code into Eclipse, I got a different error:

> The method `getName(T)` in the type `Schema` is not applicable for the arguments (`Class<capture#1-of ? extends Enum>`)

After further investigation, it doesn't appear that this is an overloading problem. In fact, this is a bit counterintuitive, because `inst.getClass()` actually *isn't* the right type for `getName(Class<T extends Enum<T> & Stringable> clazz)`.

It appears to be caused by the fact that you can't have multiple bounds for a generic type in a generic class. In other words, the type that you would expect `inst.getClass()` to return:

```
Class<? extends Enum<T> & Stringable>
```

isn't what is actually returned.

Why?

Because you can't parametrize objects with multiple bounds.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643241/why-cant-you-have-multiple-interfaces-in-a-bounded-wildcard-generic) question, it appears to be a limitation of Java; part of which is caused by the fact that Java doesn't support the right syntax to make this possible. So what is actually returned by `inst.getClass()` is:

```
Class<? extends Enum<T>>
```

And that *definitely* doesn't fit the bounds for `getName(Class<T extends Enum<T> & Stringable> clazz)` as you defined it.

Unfortunately, a quick Googling doesn't give a *really* good reason for this, so I can't answer your question as completely as I would like. But I hope this at least explains what's going on with your code.

Comment: I do thank you for the clarification on it, but that was essentially my understanding up to this point already. My main issue is why Java has this (apparent) limitation, and potential workarounds

Comment: @Rogue Ah, sorry about that then. I misunderstood what you were asking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464226/how-to-reference-a-generic-return-type-with-multiple-bounds) is another place to look, if you haven't seen it already; it gives a pretty interesting breakdown of things. I suppose a possible (yet ugly) workaround is to make your own type that is a composition of the two types, but unfortunately that doesn't work in your case...