# Type parameter bounds - Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion

Tags: java, generics, type-bounds

How can I get rid of warning `Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found 'org.example.AAndB<java.lang.integer>', required 'T'.` in following code.

I try to design an interface (`Interface`) in such a way that it wouldn't explicitly state return type of method `get()` (`AAndB<Integer>`) but rather enumerate interfaces the result has to implement (`<T extends  B<Integer> & A> T`).

```java
package org.example;

class InterfaceImpl implements Interface {

    public AAndB<Integer> get() {
        //  ^----- Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found 'org.example.AAndB<java.lang.integer>', required 'T'.
        final AAndB<Integer> aAndB = new AAndB<Integer>();
        return aAndB;
    }
}

interface Interface {
    <T extends  B<Integer> & A> T get();
}

class AAndB<T> implements A, B<T> {

    public void a() {

    }

    public void b(T t) {

    }
}

interface A {
    void a();
}

interface B<T> {
    void b(T t);
}
```

Comment: I found related question [How to reference a generic return type with multiple bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464226/how-to-reference-a-generic-return-type-with-multiple-bounds) with a comprehensive [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469627/639687).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can clearly see, your implemented method signature doesn't match the signature defined by the method in `Interface`:

```
public AAndB<Integer> get()
```

is not the same as

```
public <T extends B<Integer> & A> T get()
```

The definition of `T` is part of the method signature.  To comply with Interface.get, you would need to write:

```
class InterfaceImpl implements Interface {
    public <T extends B<Integer> & A> T get() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Bounded generics in an interface's method signature do not mean that you can substitute any type which lies within the bounds in your own implementation of the method.

If you want to be able to specify different return types, you need to parameterize `Interface`:

```
class InterfaceImpl implements Interface<AAndB<Integer>> {

    public AAndB<Integer> get() {
        final AAndB<Integer> aAndB = new AAndB<Integer>();
        return aAndB;
    }
}

interface Interface<T extends B<Integer> & A> {
     T get();
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the original `InterfaceImpl` doesn't actually implement the `Interface`?

Comment: Updated with more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You are completely misunderstanding what `<T extends  B<Integer> & A> T get();` means.

`<T extends  B<Integer> & A> T get();` declares a *generic method*. That means the method must be able to work correctly with any `T` -- it must work correctly with `T` being whatever any caller could potentially want `T` to be, without even knowing what `T` is.

It does not mean the method can choose `T` to be what it wants. It's the opposite. The method has no choice and has to work with any `T` chosen for it.