# How to have an arraylist of general objects as argument?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I have a method to remove an object from the list, this is used to create a `listView` so the object is removed using the index of the `listview` item selected. But I want the method to work for several types of objects i.e., I have more than one `listview`.

```
public void removeFromList(ListView<Label> listView, ArrayList<objects?> arrayList){
        int minus = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        arrayList.remove(minus);
        listView.getItems().remove(minus);
}
```

Comment: Remove `objects`.

Comment: Clarify more your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the wildcard bound:

```
ArrayList<?> arrayList
```

This allows you to pass any `ArrayList` to the method.

Comment: You also can use `List<?>` for every kind of List and `<? extends A>` if you want to say "I will allow multiple types but from..."
For example you want to use employee/worker/...-list so ? need to  extend the class `Person`

Comment: @LenglBoy indeed. After all, `List<?>` is ([roughly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055389/whats-the-difference-between-and-extends-object-in-java-generics)) the same as `List<? extends Object>`, so it's implicitly upper bounded to `Object`. If you want a tighter bound, you just need to be explicit.