# Java - Is "extends Object" really necessary on some Collections method specifications?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

According to [Collections definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), methods like `max` and `min` have the following signature:

```
static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

I was wondering why that `extends Object` would be necessary, as only `T` is supposed to mean "any type" anyway. As an example, for the `sort` method definition, from the same documentation, we have only `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` as expected.

Is there any reason for that `extends Object` in `max` and `min` specifications?

Comment: In spite of the title of that question, it truly is a duplicate.  The answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055497/5174436) even uses the same example as the OP.