# Passing generic list to supertype without explicit casting

Tags: java

I use an API which has this method:

```
public void doSomething(List<Object> list);
```

On our application side we have only one certain class say 'MyClass' that should be passed to this api method.

So for this restriction I created a method which will call the API:

```
public void myMethod(List<MyClass>list){
 api.doSomething(list);
}
```

Of course it doesnt compile and I cant use wild cards because I cant touch the api code. Right now I am casting the MyClass generic to Object by hand.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: You can cast it to `List`: `api.doSomething((List) list);`.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, you can either have `myMethod(List<?> list)` or `myMethod(List list)`. They will probably receive a warning but not an error, at least the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing something simple like;

```
public static void myMethod(List<MyClass> list) {
    doSomething(new ArrayList<>(list));
}
```

Unless you are removing or adding things to the list, you can use this. Otherwise since you will be instantiating a new list, any changes to it will be lost and not reflected to your `list`, but changes on the individual elements of `MyClass` objects will be.

Answer (score 2):

No, the API definition is *"wrong"* (if you want to avoid casting). A best API definition could be:

```
// *external* API
static class API {
    public void doSomething(List<? extends Object> list) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("not implemented");
    }
}
```

Now, you can call with any `? extending Object`:

```
List<String> xs = new ArrayList<>();

new API().doSomething(xs);
```

As a side note, any object extend `Object` then `? extends Object` is redundant. **This** API could be rewritten as:

```
public void doSomething(List<?> list)
```

But in general, you will have something like:

```
public void doSomething(List<ApiDataModel> list)
```

Then, the proper way is again:

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends ApiDataModel> list)
```

Comment: Well, you could replace `<? extends Object>` with simply `<?>`, because [they are synonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055497/507738).

Comment: Yes but to understand it I think is better my explicit version.

Comment: @josejuan `<?>` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Of course @AndyTurner, but I want reforce the `extend` idea (i'll update to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a List from List in this way:

```
public void myMethod(List<MyClass> list){
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    objectList.addAll(list)
    api.doSomething(objectList);
}
```

Or simply use a non-generic cast (this will generate a warning):

```
public void myMethod(List<MyClass> list){
    api.doSomething((List)list);
}
```

Comment: "Or simply use a non-generic cast (this will generate a warning):" You should point out the danger that the warning is highlighting: that `doSomething` is allowed to add instances of any subclass of `Object` to the parameter list, which could then break the type safety of other things using `list`.